# How to implement lines inside an AppBar?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

I would like to know if it's possible (And if it is how I could do that) to implement lines in an AppBar like in this figure: [image]
I made the design on Figma and I would like to replicate it in flutter

Comment: Is the line is transparent, reflecting the background ?

Comment: Yes, but I could set the same color

Comment: Try with CustomPaint or ClipPath with   `Path.combine(PathOperation.difference,`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am using `ClipPath` to have the paith, you can use `CustomPaint` with this path. Next creating new Widget implementing `PreferredSizeWidget`  to place this on `apBar`

```dart
class AppBarClipPath extends CustomClipper<Path> {
  @override
  Path getClip(Size size) {
    const radius = Radius.circular(24);
    Path bgPath = Path()
      ..addRRect(
        RRect.fromRectAndCorners(Rect.fromLTRB(0, 0, size.width, size.height),
            bottomRight: radius, bottomLeft: radius),
      );

    ///middle curve
    const thickness = 10.0;
    Path middleCurve = Path()
      ..moveTo(20, size.height)
      ..quadraticBezierTo(
          0, size.height * .3, size.width * .7, size.height * .5)
      ..quadraticBezierTo(size.width * .9, size.height * .5, size.width - 20, 0)
      ..lineTo(size.width - 20 + thickness, 0)
      ..quadraticBezierTo(size.width, size.height * .5, size.width * .7,
          size.height * .5 + thickness)
      ..quadraticBezierTo(0, size.height * .4, 20 + thickness, size.height)
      ..lineTo(size.width, size.height);

    return Path.combine(PathOperation.difference, bgPath, middleCurve);
  }

  @override
  bool shouldReclip(covariant CustomClipper<Path> oldClipper) => false;
}
```

```dart
class MyCustomAppBar extends StatelessWidget implements PreferredSizeWidget {
  const MyCustomAppBar({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ClipPath(
      clipper: AppBarClipPath(),
      child: Container(
        color: Colors.deepPurple,
      ),
    );
  }

  @override
  Size get preferredSize => const Size.fromHeight(200);
}
```

And use

```dart
return Scaffold(
  appBar: MyCustomAppBar(),
```

As you can see, it needs to improve on `quadraticBezierTo` but you've got the concept of creating this.

[image]

Comment: instead of `appBar: MyCustomAppBar()` use a built-in `ApoBar` class as it has `shape` property

Comment: I had thought about that, but then I thought for newcomers some may get afraid of overriding ShapeBorder methods(I might be wrong).  I think my focus was shifted to creating a separate widget. And yes I missed the shape on Appbar, thought about Container.

Comment: but such Container is almost useless: it is flat, no actions, no back button...

Comment: Then my mind was shifted on PreferredSizeWidget and sliverPersistentHeaderDelegate(I think), I will try shape from next on. Thanks for pointing out.

Comment: and the most interesting thing is it provides "shape morphing" - try the above code and press the center button and you will see how appbar's shape changes - all you have to do is to call `setState`

Comment: Yea, It is cool

Comment: "I thought for newcomers some may get afraid of overriding ShapeBorder methods", so you can always use `abstract class SimpleShapeBorder extends ShapeBorder {
@override
EdgeInsetsGeometry get dimensions => EdgeInsets.zero;

@override
ui.Path getInnerPath(Rect rect, {ui.TextDirection? textDirection}) => getClip(rect);

@override
ui.Path getOuterPath(Rect rect, {ui.TextDirection? textDirection}) => getClip(rect);

@override
void paint(ui.Canvas canvas, Rect rect, {ui.TextDirection? textDirection}) {}

@override
ShapeBorder scale(double t) => this;
ui.Path getClip(Rect rect);
}`

Comment: and instead of extending `ShapeBorder` with 5 methods, extend `SimpleShapeBorder` where you need to implement only one `getClip` method - just like in `CustomClipper`